# Javascript: Put array into a text field

Tags: javascript, arrays, textarea

How would you go about putting an array into a textarea, each value on its own line? I thought about converting the array to a string, and the commas into new lines, but what if the value of an array item has a comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the array's join() method:

```
["a", "b", "c"].join("\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
myarray.join("\n")
```

put that as the textarea value

Answer (score 1):

Try with join

```
text = array.join("");
document.write(text); // or what ever you would do with text
```

Comment: Won't be on separate lines per SO request

Answer (score 0):

If you have a comma delimited array that contains values with unescaped commas, you have an insurmountable problem. You need to convert the array into a string with some other sort of delimiter, preferably the linebreaks you want them to be in the end.

Comment: Rofl. Good point. So scratch that concern. Would my stated approach be the best way of going about it?

Comment: Some of the other answers have examples of using the array's `join` method with `\n` as the delimiter. That would be a good way to go.